# Android - Unexpected setExecutionWindow() behaviour in OneoffTask.Builder

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating a `GcmTaskService` which I call with a `OneoffTask`.

I am not sure the `windowEndDelaySeconds` value I pass to the `setExecution()` method of `OneoffTask.Builder` is being utilised correctly. Or maybe I just don't understand the [documentation for OneoffTask.Builder's setExecution()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask.Builder.html#setExecutionWindow(long,%20long)):

> **public OneoffTask.Builder setExecutionWindow (long windowStartDelaySeconds, long windowEndDelaySeconds)**
>
> Mandatory setter for creating a one-off task. You specify the earliest
>   point in time in the future from which your task might start
>   executing, as well as the latest point in time in the future at which
>   your task must have executed.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> windowStartDelaySeconds - Earliest point from which your task is eligible to run. windowEndDelaySeconds - Latest point at
>   which your task must be run.

When I do the following:

1. Disable connectivity on my device
2. Schedule my task with an end time of 1 second - using `.setExecutionWindow(0, 1)`
3. Wait 10 seconds
4. Enable connectivity on my device

...my task executes - despite it being much later than the 1 second `windowEndDelaySeconds` value I specified in the `OneoffTask.Builder`. Why is this?

**My code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.OneoffTask;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.TaskParams;

public class TestTaskService extends GcmTaskService {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = TestTaskService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ACTION_TEST = "ACTION_TEST";
    private static final String EXTRA_ACTION = "EXTRA_ACTION";
    private static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

    public static void startActionTest(Context context, String message) {

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(EXTRA_ACTION, ACTION_TEST);
        extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

        OneoffTask task = new OneoffTask.Builder()
                .setService(TestTaskService.class)
                .setExtras(extras)
                .setTag(ACTION_TEST)
                .setExecutionWindow(0, 1) // seconds
                .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build();

        GcmNetworkManager gcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context);
        gcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);

    }

    @Override
    public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Bundle extras = taskParams.getExtras();
        String action = extras.getString(EXTRA_ACTION);
        if (ACTION_TEST.equals(action)) {

            String message = extras.getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            if (message == null) {
                message = "No message.";
            }
            Utilities.makeToast(context, message);
            return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unknown action: " + action);
            Utilities.makeToast(context, "Unknown action: " + action);
            return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_FAILURE;
        }

    }

}
```

...called with `TestTaskService.startActionTest(context, "My message");`

Comment: You didn't mention what's the expected behavior. Was it "if the conditions are not met until `windowEnd` do not run the task at all"?

Comment: The docs describe the end time as the `latest point at which your task must be run`. So I would expect that if my task hasn't been run after 1 second, then it won't be run at all.

Comment: But that isn't the case, so can anyone provide a better/fuller explanation of the `windowEndDelaySeconds` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Given `start=600` and `end=3600` the job will run between 10 minutes and 1 hour from now as soon as the conditions are met (e.g. required connectivity) or 1 hour from now if the conditions aren't met. It is up to you to determine which is it or check the conditions when the job is run.

The opposing idea that the job shouldn't run at all if the conditions aren't met until `end` is therefore false.

> #### Schedule a one-off task when network is connected
>
> Your app can schedule a one-off task to execute only when the user is connected to an unmetered (non-cellular) network, in order to conserve your users' data. The example below shows a task that will execute as soon as the user has an unmetered connection, or at latest one hour after scheduling:
>
> ```
> OneoffTask task = new OneoffTask.Builder()
>     .setService(MyTaskService.class)
>     .setTag(TASK_TAG_WIFI)
>     .setExecutionWindow(0L, 3600L)
>     .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_UNMETERED)
>     .build();
>
> mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
> ```

Source: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager

Comment: Thanks, but if that was the case then my task should have been run 1 second after scheduling (as the end time had been reached with the conditions not being met). But it only ran (much later) when the conditions *were* met.

Comment: Are you sure it's not this behavior? `Note that you can request a one-off task to be executed at any point in the future, but to prevent abuse the scheduler will only set an alarm at a minimum of 30 seconds in the future. Your task can still be run earlier than this if some network event occurs to wake up the scheduler.` Source: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the situation here. I get the same outcome that I described in my question even if I introduce a step **3a** - restarting the device. Please give my code a try and you should see it for yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Strange documentation. Does it mean that the task will be executed after 1h even if conditions are not met? I don't think so that's the case.

Comment: @malachiasz that's what happens according to docs. You're responsible for checking the conditions when the task starts. Then react accordingly. Either do the work if conditions are met, or reschedule the task. Or adjust the workload, I don't know your particular use case.